# Are nested transaction supported?

Tags: vb6, adodb

I have a legacy application coded in vb6 with  ADODB library, connecting to a Microsoft SQL server 2008. 
Can I create nested transactions (classe Connection.BeginTrans ? )

How can I know if it is supported indeed ?

Comment: Have you tried it on a sample data set?

Comment: I have tried, it actually does not crash, but what would be the corret way of being sure it does actually work ?

Comment: Looking at the results seems the obvious way.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 does supported nested transactions.

The best way to tell if it is indeed supported in your code is to check the return value of Connection.BeginTrans. The return value will increment by 1 for each nested transaction.

So, if you call it twice and nested transactions are working, then the return value will be 2. For the third call, it will be 3, etc.

Committing or Rolling Back will decrease the return value by 1.

See here for documentation on the function that says as much:

https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_conn_begintrans.asp

Good Luck.